# Refreshing bean when underlying dependent bean gets updated in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a config as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class REConfiguration {

  private final DBRuleLoader dbRuleLoader;

  
  public REConfiguration(
      DBRuleLoader dbRuleLoader) {
    this.dbRuleLoader = dbRuleLoader;
  }

  
  @RefreshScope
  @Bean
  public REMgr ruleEngine() {
    return REmgrFactory.getREMgr(this.dbRuleLoader);
  }

}
```

Actually, I have added `@RefreshScope` here, as I want on any update of underlying `DBRuleLoader` bean, `REMgr` gets refreshed. I am not sure if it actually works.

Comment: it will work check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833517/175554, for testing put some log in your ruleEngine() and change the config files in your classpath and call those beans after.